# ES6 Attaching a url to a mapped object from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, get

I'm working on a side project with React and I'm using the tmdb API.

My GET request

```
performSearch = () => { // Requesting data from API
    axios.get(`${URL}api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchInput}${PARAMS}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.results);
            this.setState({ searchResults: res.data.results});
        });
}
```

And I render the results with the map function like so

```
 const Suggestions = (props) => {
  const options = props.searchResults.map(r => (
    <li className='search-results'
      key={r.id} >
      {r.title}
      {r.name}
      {r.poster_path}
    </li>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}

export default Suggestions
```

What I need is this URL 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300' + {r.poster_path} to render out the image, how do I go about doing that? End result looks like this 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/gwPSoYUHAKmdyVywgLpKKA4BjRr.jpg'

Comment: Where should the image be? In the <li>?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `URL + {r.poster_path}` to an image tag's src attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as an attribute into an img-object. For example, using template strings:

```
 const Suggestions = (props) => {
   const options = props.searchResults.map((r) => (
     <li className='search-results' key={r.id}>
       {r.title}
       {r.name}
       <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${r.poster_path}`} alt={r.title} />
     </li>
   ))
   return <ul>{options}</ul>
 };

 export default Suggestions
```

Comment: Damn, looks like i was pretty close, I just needed that $ Thanks bro